# The usage of かな and かしら

Tags: usage, nuances, particles

質問があるんですが、「かしら」と「かな」は終助詞ですね。どう違いますか？どう使った方がいいんですか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

意味は同じです。どちらも何かを疑問に思う時に使います。

しかし、「かしら」は（現実では東京の一地方の方言、創作では女性の役割語であって）あまり標準語とは言えないので、特に使わなくていいと思います。